# Why would file_put_contents() succeed but touch() fail?

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm running a script that makes some changes to the contents of a file then resets its modification time to what it was before.  Intermittently, I'll find the following errors in my log:

> ```
> touch() [function.touch]: Utime
> failed: Operation not permitted
> ```

This on the line immediately after a `file_put_contents()` call appears to have changed the contents of the file I tried to `touch()`.  There are no errors associated with the `file_put_contents()` line.

Has anyone had this happen?  Can anyone figure out what set of permissions would allow me to write a file but not change its modification time?  I'm doing this on Linux.

Comment: Depends on the OS, which one are you doing this on?

Comment: Linux, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug with PHP's `touch` command. Even if you have write permission to the file, it fails if PHP isn't also the "owner".

If you're using Apache and Linux, use this command on your server's console to make PHP the file's owner:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /YourPATH/YourFILE
```

Better still, update the entire folder containing files you want PHP to control:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /YourPATH/YourFOLDER
```

---

**Side Note:** Because PHP can write to the file, that means it must have user or group write permission. Since that's the case, touch should not behave this way. It seems like a bug.

Comment: We had a similar problem where a file's content should be replaced but the modification file time needed to be kept. Because of what you answered here we needed to `unlink` the old file and create the new one on the desired location and afterwards apply the `touch` operation in order to achieve the desired result. Possibly this also solves your problem: Delete the file you're trying to replace in first place, afterwards place the new file at desired location and update timestamps. Possibly doing a `chown($f, get_current_user());` before `touch()`also solves the problem.

Comment: No, I would never advise deleting and re-creaing files simply to set date modified. This is a needles drain on disk usage, especially if done frequently. Worse still, if writing is interrupted or not allowed, you've just deleted the file. It's now gone forever.

Comment: I agree with that. But as long as it's about *replacing file contents while keeping original file's modification timestamp*, it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the file gets created with wrong permissions. Try to chmod 777 the file just after the file_put_contents and then touch the file.

Comment: Is the user who is running the php script the owner of the file / parent directory? that could be also another useful check

Answer (score 0):

As rossoft says, PHP is probably not the owner of the file. But setting the permissions to 777 might not be the best solution. I'd preferr:

```
function touch_file($file) {
    fclose(fopen($file, 'a'));
}

touch_file('/path/to/file');
```

Comment: I would do that, but I'm trying to use touch with a time in the past.

Comment: This did not work for us for whatever reason. But the following did `file_put_contents($file, "");`.

Answer (score 0):

Only recently, I've had a similar problem and I think I know the answer.

The actual purpose of touch() is to update the modification and access times of a file.  Creating the file is just a side-effect.

If you're using Linux, but writing to an NTFS partition as you might with a dual-boot configuration, depending on how the partition is mounted, touch() might have problems changing the access time on files.  The file will be created, but touch() will still fail because the underlying system returns an error status.  The same thing can be observed from the command line where you'll get a "permission denied" message.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding this in the man pages for mount, ntfs-3g, or touch (Linux command), but the problem is mentioned in the comments on the [touch()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) PHP function page.

Tweaking mount options might provide a solution, but you're better off using [is_writable()](http://my.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) to check permissions and [fopen()](http://my.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to create files.